# How to debug systemd shutdown failing to gracefully shutdown?

Tags: systemd, process, shutdown

I have a host that runs qemu vms. But that is irrelevant for the systemd question context. It could be any other process which terminates perfectly fine with a sigterm/sighup.

Every restart will leave the qemu pidfile around, showing its process wasn't properly terminated but possibly killed ...question here is exactly how to find out what happened.

bellow is all the investigation steps, but in the end, the root cause is: systemd sends a `SIGKILL` while either not sending a `SIGTERM`/`SIGHUP`, or sending `SIGTERM`/`SIGHUP` and then following up with `SIGKILL` in under a second (when all timeouts are over 1min)

Nowhere in the logs systemd shows any reason for sending the `SIGKILL`. hence this question.

```
$ journalctl -b -1
...
systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
...
systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
systemd[1]: Shutting down.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
systemd-journald[523]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
systemd-journald[523]: Journal stopped
```

qemu logs doesn't have anything besides startup, which tells me it never got a sigterm signal but was killed. I can't find any mention of it on any logs though...

```
$ systemctl status systemd-shutdown
Unit systemd-shutdown.service could not be found.

$ systemctl show systemd-shutdown
ExitType=main
Restart=no
NotifyAccess=none
RestartUSec=100ms
TimeoutStartUSec=1min 30s
TimeoutStopUSec=1min 30s
TimeoutAbortUSec=1min 30s
TimeoutStartFailureMode=terminate
TimeoutStopFailureMode=terminate
RuntimeMaxUSec=infinity
RuntimeRandomizedExtraUSec=0
WatchdogUSec=infinity
WatchdogTimestampMonotonic=0
RootDirectoryStartOnly=no
RemainAfterExit=no
GuessMainPID=yes
MainPID=0
ControlPID=0
FileDescriptorStoreMax=0
NFileDescriptorStore=0
StatusErrno=0
Result=success
ReloadResult=success
CleanResult=success
UID=[not set]
GID=[not set]
NRestarts=0
ReloadSignal=1
ExecMainStartTimestampMonotonic=0
ExecMainExitTimestampMonotonic=0
ExecMainPID=0
ExecMainCode=0
ExecMainStatus=0
ControlGroupId=0
MemoryCurrent=[not set]
MemoryAvailable=infinity
CPUUsageNSec=[not set]
TasksCurrent=[not set]
IPIngressBytes=[no data]
IPIngressPackets=[no data]
IPEgressBytes=[no data]
IPEgressPackets=[no data]
IOReadBytes=18446744073709551615
IOReadOperations=18446744073709551615
IOWriteBytes=18446744073709551615
IOWriteOperations=18446744073709551615
Delegate=no
CPUAccounting=yes
CPUWeight=[not set]
StartupCPUWeight=[not set]
CPUShares=[not set]
StartupCPUShares=[not set]
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
IOAccounting=no
IOWeight=[not set]
StartupIOWeight=[not set]
BlockIOAccounting=no
BlockIOWeight=[not set]
StartupBlockIOWeight=[not set]
MemoryAccounting=yes
DefaultMemoryLow=0
DefaultMemoryMin=0
MemoryMin=0
MemoryLow=0
MemoryHigh=infinity
MemoryMax=infinity
MemorySwapMax=infinity
MemoryZSwapMax=infinity
MemoryLimit=infinity
DevicePolicy=auto
TasksAccounting=yes
TasksMax=37597
IPAccounting=no
ManagedOOMSwap=auto
ManagedOOMMemoryPressure=auto
ManagedOOMMemoryPressureLimit=0
ManagedOOMPreference=none
UMask=0022
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitCPUSoft=infinity
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitFSIZESoft=infinity
LimitDATA=infinity
LimitDATASoft=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity
LimitSTACKSoft=8388608
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitCORESoft=infinity
LimitRSS=infinity
LimitRSSSoft=infinity
LimitNOFILE=1073741816
LimitNOFILESoft=1073741816
LimitAS=infinity
LimitASSoft=infinity
LimitNPROC=125324
LimitNPROCSoft=125324
LimitMEMLOCK=4116402176
LimitMEMLOCKSoft=4116402176
LimitLOCKS=infinity
LimitLOCKSSoft=infinity
LimitSIGPENDING=125324
LimitSIGPENDINGSoft=125324
LimitMSGQUEUE=819200
LimitMSGQUEUESoft=819200
LimitNICE=0
LimitNICESoft=0
LimitRTPRIO=0
LimitRTPRIOSoft=0
LimitRTTIME=infinity
LimitRTTIMESoft=infinity
OOMScoreAdjust=0
CoredumpFilter=0x33
Nice=0
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=4
CPUSchedulingPolicy=0
CPUSchedulingPriority=0
CPUAffinityFromNUMA=no
NUMAPolicy=n/a
TimerSlackNSec=50000
CPUSchedulingResetOnFork=no
NonBlocking=no
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
TTYReset=no
TTYVHangup=no
TTYVTDisallocate=no
SyslogPriority=30
SyslogLevelPrefix=yes
SyslogLevel=6
SyslogFacility=3
LogLevelMax=-1
LogRateLimitIntervalUSec=0
LogRateLimitBurst=0
SecureBits=0
CapabilityBoundingSet=cap_chown cap_dac_override cap_dac_read_search cap_fowner cap_fsetid cap_kill cap_setgid cap_setuid cap_setpcap cap_linux_immutable cap_net_bind_service cap_net_broadcast cap_net_admin cap_net_raw cap_ipc_lock cap_ipc_owner cap_sys_module cap_sys_rawio cap_sys_chroot cap_sys_ptrace cap_sys_pacct cap_sys_admin cap_sys_boot cap_sys_nice cap_sys_resource cap_sys_time cap_sys_tty_config cap_mknod cap_lease cap_audit_write cap_audit_control cap_setfcap cap_mac_override cap_mac_admin cap_syslog cap_wake_alarm cap_block_suspend cap_audit_read cap_perfmon cap_bpf cap_checkpoint_restore
DynamicUser=no
RemoveIPC=no
PrivateTmp=no
PrivateDevices=no
ProtectClock=no
ProtectKernelTunables=no
ProtectKernelModules=no
ProtectKernelLogs=no
ProtectControlGroups=no
PrivateNetwork=no
PrivateUsers=no
PrivateMounts=no
PrivateIPC=no
ProtectHome=no
ProtectSystem=no
SameProcessGroup=no
UtmpMode=init
IgnoreSIGPIPE=yes
NoNewPrivileges=no
SystemCallErrorNumber=2147483646
LockPersonality=no
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=no
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
StateDirectoryMode=0755
CacheDirectoryMode=0755
LogsDirectoryMode=0755
ConfigurationDirectoryMode=0755
TimeoutCleanUSec=infinity
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=no
RestrictRealtime=no
RestrictSUIDSGID=no
RestrictNamespaces=no
MountAPIVFS=no
KeyringMode=private
ProtectProc=default
ProcSubset=all
ProtectHostname=no
KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=15
RestartKillSignal=15
FinalKillSignal=9
SendSIGKILL=yes
SendSIGHUP=no
WatchdogSignal=6
Id=systemd-shutdown.service
Names=systemd-shutdown.service
Description=systemd-shutdown.service
LoadState=not-found
ActiveState=inactive
FreezerState=running
SubState=dead
StateChangeTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
CanStart=no
CanStop=yes
CanReload=no
CanIsolate=no
CanFreeze=yes
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnSuccessJobMode=fail
OnFailureJobMode=replace
IgnoreOnIsolate=no
NeedDaemonReload=no
JobTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobRunningTimeoutUSec=infinity
JobTimeoutAction=none
ConditionResult=no
AssertResult=no
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=0
AssertTimestampMonotonic=0
LoadError=org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit "Unit systemd-shutdown.service not found."
Transient=no
Perpetual=no
StartLimitIntervalUSec=10s
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitAction=none
FailureAction=none
SuccessAction=none
CollectMode=inactive
```

There's no systemd unit for qemu as the users should start them adhoc for development. The usual way to stop it is `pkill -F <qemu pid file>`, which sends a SIGTERM and it exits fine and very quickly (couple milliseconds) and results in a shutdown message on the qemu log file.

```
$ time pkill ...
real    0m0.036s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.012s
```

(it is usually 0.003s. the above command was issue during vm startup, which is the worst case for a shutdown). So not a termination timeout by any means.

Only a few times i will see this (possibly when a dev is running qemu without the daemonize/background option):

```
systemd[735]: Stopped Firefox Web Browser - Web Browser.
systemd[735]: app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope, ignoring: Operation not permitted
systemd[735]: app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope: Killing process 13618 (qemu-system-x86) with signal SIGKILL.
systemd[735]: app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope: Killing process 13622 (kvm-nx-lpage-recovery-13618) with signal SIGKILL.
systemd[735]: app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope, ignoring: Operation not permitted
systemd[735]: Stopped Konsole - Terminal.
systemd[735]: app-org.kde.konsole-123.scope: Consumed 7min 31.417s CPU time.
systemd[735]: Removed slice User Background Tasks Slice.
systemd[735]: background.slice: Consumed 5min 46.912s CPU time.
```

```
QEMU emulator version 8.0.2
systemd 253.6
kernel 6.4.3
```

Any ideas on how to debug or fix this bad shutdown of qemu during systemd-shutdown?

edit, couple months later:

with systemd 254.4-1 now i get more information. It does SIGKILL my qemu process:

```
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd-logind[721]: The system will reboot now!
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd-logind[721]: System is rebooting.
Sep 22 18:38:50 local sddm-helper[850]: Signal received: SIGTERM
...
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd-logind[721]: Removed session 1.
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd[854]: Activating special unit Exit the Session...
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd[854]: app-org.kde.konsole-1ab3dac6a1db4b29b55899b477b32975.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/>
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd[854]: app-org.kde.konsole-1ab3dac6a1db4b29b55899b477b32975.scope: Killing process 1708 (qemu-system-x86) with signal SIGKILL.
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd[854]: app-org.kde.konsole-1ab3dac6a1db4b29b55899b477b32975.scope: Killing process 1712 (kvm-nx-lpage-recovery-1708) with signal SIGKILL.
Sep 22 18:38:50 local systemd[854]: app-org.kde.konsole-1ab3dac6a1db4b29b55899b477b32975.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/>
```

But it decides to SIGKILL it in the same second as shutdown started. More questions. From the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), it seems the timeout is defined via `TimeoutStopSec=` which missing when i `show` the special shutdown service, and it is also not present for `show systemd.service` either. It does have `TimeoutStopUSec=1min 30s` there though, which is documented to be the default for the other TimeoutStop values. But it definitely did not wait 1m30s...

```
$ ps tree
systemd─┬─NetworkManager───4*[{NetworkManager}]
      ....
        ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)   
      ...
        │         ├─qemu-system-x86───9*[{qemu-system-x86}]
      ...
```

More debug info

```
$ df /sys/fs/cgroup
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
cgroup2                0     0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup

$ systemctl show -p Delegate session-1.scope
Delegate=no

# sample cgroup (wm might differ)
CGROUP
0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.kde.konsole-a1s82fe5b97a47fb9ab9030b2b383cbc.scope
```

Comment: not clear what is missing. have all relevant versions and system logs. english is my 4th language, so my questions will not have perfect prose nor i will get any stab at my writing in it, unless they are direct and to the point.

Comment: well, searching for this again, i got to my own question again. versions are now updated to `qmeu 8.1.1` `systemd 254.4-1` `kernel 6.5.4` and system usage still sucks.

Comment: It's not spelled out on the `pkill ...` part of the question, but `qemu` does clear the pidfile *correctly* on both `SIGTERM` and `SIGHUP`. So it is not being killed that way.

Comment: "There's no systemd unit for qemu...", that's your problem. Start using systemd units and your problem will be solved. Users should also use systemd user units. (Example for user unit control: `systemctl --user enable ~/myunitfile.service`, also read the documentation for systemd units.)

Comment: @paladin thanks but i fail to see how that is practical or a solution. Devs use qemu for adhoc dev/test vms. you are asking someone to create unit files for text editors and browsers next? :)  a init system should do what it says it does: `send SIGTERM/SIGHUP, wait, send SIGKILL`. yet systemd is just sending SIGKILL right away.

Comment: It's not the fault of the init system. Your hypervisor is not able to gracefully shut down in time, cause it tries to shutdown the running virtual machines too. This takes time, probably too much time and then the init system uses its default timeout for "not responding" processes and kills it. So better tell your init system to wait a bit more and/or make unit dependencies. Creating a unit file is done within 3 minutes, and you may use templates for faster creation too. I strongly suggest to you to use user unit files. It's easy, give it a try. ;-)

Comment: @paladin that is blatantly wrong. i show in two different places it shutdow gracefully in under .5s just fine. One when i issue the sigterm myself, and another when i show on journal timestamps.

Comment: systemd doesn't attempt to gracefully shutdown processes it doesn't control. Only those it started itself or at least children of those it knows about. So your expectation is wrong. If you want systemd to deal with qemu gracefully, make it start those qemu processes too. It is as @paladin suggests, create units and educate users to use those units. Or implement libvirt, or install Proxmox VE — both create systemd units on demand and are user-friendly so you don't need to bother with systemd yourself.

Comment: You could even alias the start of the qm to be used via systemd, Think f.e. the switch between initd and systemd startscripts.
Nikitias answer shows imho the source of the problem, given i had systemd shutdown problems with unsafe shutdown processes some time ago as well which were exactly unsupervised processes.

However User context itself (the process is started by a user, which depending on config  might already be within a Unit) potentially could be used to solve this. Even something like a shutdown unit file sigterming processes per user before "full" shutdown via dependancy cfg unit

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov all those process are under `systemd>plasmashell>konsole>qemu` or `systemd>gnome-session>gnome-terminal>qemu`. I do get `sigterm` on firefox just fine which is also under `systemd>windowmanager`...   besides, it's common practice in all init systems to send a sigterm on shutdown, and sigkill in last case... i doubt system does so on purpose, even against its own docs. if that is the case, then please, update their docs (i link to one on the question even)

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode= `Defaults to control-group.` which `all remaining processes in the control group of this unit will be killed on unit stop`  and https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html# `FinalKillSignal= Specifies which signal to send to remaining processes after a timeout if SendSIGKILL= is enabled` ...you all are saying there's no timeout and there's no cgroup mode?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov +paladin i guess you are all correct if you were saying there's no timeout, which i don't think you were... i've sent a patch to their man pages.

Answer (score 1):

Since all commenters are more interested in offering a fix to the sample problem and not find how to debug why systemd was doing what it was doing (*which was the question*), i will start with that: Answer was my system (systemd by default? my distro?) had `killMode=mixed` for the `user.service` unit, despite the [manual saying the default is `control-group`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=) and I did not change the default :shrug.

Well, what that mixed mode does: sends sighup to the main process (my shell i guess?) and then sigkill to all others in the cgroup. "it's all about faster reboots" was *not* a joke after all.

Since the question was to find out **why** that was happening, i guess the answer is

> Systemd will not tell you about it's action based on killmode. It's up to you to know every possible configuration and edge case, and infer the root cause from final effects. No solution.

---

here's some more investigation with very similar loss of data from killed user processes but. i'm very salty since it sucked all my free time in the last workday. enjoy.

Seems to be a behavior change they are dealing with for years? There are bug reports (all with traction, some with patches, zero actual closure to the end) since 2014-10! when it was [ignored on the mailing](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-October/024465.html) list. Then distros started to open bugs around 2015-04

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1448259

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1170765

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274537

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1394937

...many more. All in the same state: Lot's of discussion. Confusion on the basics of reproducing a simple signal logger (gotta love how even systemd team doesn't even try to look at their own logs and diag, the only debug was "added some log_unit_debug to systemd" whatever that means). drags on for months with everyone trying to use shell history files as the only way to test this, moves to clean bugs because old ones were noisy, more talk, and some automated system close it as invalid based on time. lol. typical red hat support we got when we still paid for it before getting even worse support from aws.

Discussed on [item 5 of this meeting](https://meetbot-raw.fedoraproject.org/fedora-blocker-review/2016-11-14/f25-blocker-review.2016-11-14-17.00.html). they don't even have devs in those anymore by then. and the main [concern they had](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1394937#c6) was balancing between loss-of-data vs a rare hangup of 180seconds on shutdown. That kinda confirm all the "systemd main goal is fast reboots" jokes, sadly. that thread then seems to have the support folks lost on understanding how bash saves history. Then one of them hits a issue with gnome-terminal crashing on shutdown on wayland only (original report was kde on X11... lol) and the bug sidelines.

...meanwhile all the distro and other [affected people](https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/1155#issuecomment-160888071) closed their own bugs as the distros patched the rollback themselves

they actually reverted the code causing this in 2016 when it got visibility on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3azlv0/tts1141137_systemd_sends_sigkill_imediately_after/) of all places... but at this point i gave up. not even sure this is related to the thing that was affecting me as i did not read any code while following this. edit: yeah looks like. they [added the mixed killMode](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/58ea275a68cd242ad60161bcb7582614d1d89f13?diff=split#diff-7205806ee9ce59966e0c08df919c9e8b45177120187a5b2ff459c8f3a7c4f065L106) by the end of 2014 with no review/PR because "This *should* fix some race with terminating systemd".

--
edit 1

also found out they [replace property names because of leaky internal representations when you use `systemclt show`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1018335)... all your `TimeOutSec` turn into `TimeOutUSec` just to screw up your debugging session even further :)